# Can OpenGL implement an Alpha amination

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I know the AlphaAnimation can do this easily, but I need draw the bitmap alpha change gradually in GLSurfaceView, how to do this ?

I look up the GLES20 class, but i can't found any method can do what I want, So Painful TwT.

If anyone has the example, Please notify me, many thanks.

Comment: Please add code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer:
Use a FRAGMENT_SHADER can do this, like

> precision mediump float;
>   uniform float a_text_alpha;
>   varying vec2 v_texCoord;
>   uniform sampler2D s_texture;
>   void main() {
>   gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ) *a_text_alpha ; 
>                    };

change  "**a_text_alpha**" varying